# rigidbody2d constant velocity based on direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I currently have this script (don't read too much into the code, not everything is pasted here, only what is needed to understand the question):

```
Touch[] touches = Input.touches;
Vector2 dir = (Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (touches [i].position).GetPoint (0) - obj.getGameObject ().transform.position).normalized * speed;
obj.getGameObject ().GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = dir;
```

The problem is that the speed of the rigidbody is different based on distance from the object to the touched point, so the speed will be 2x or more if you touch a point distant from the gameobject, compared to a point close to the gameobject.

How would I go about fixing this, so I can achieve a constant velocity which isn't based on distance from the gameobject?

Comment: But you use normalized vector so it should work, it doesn't?

Comment: @JerrySwitalski No it doesnt, the object moves faster if the distance from the object is further away. so it moves very slowly if distance is just next to it, and the opposite, very fast if the distance is long away.

Comment: That is weird. Maybe try to store the Vector2 before * speed, and call on it .Normalize() as for me your code is good.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski that didnt work, it had the same effect as before :/

Comment: Have you tried outputting `dir` using `Debug.Log()`, and maybe the magnitude of `dir` and `velocity`? Presently your code doesn't suggest anything that would cause what you're describing, so more information is warranted. You're sure there isn't any other code/physics that may be acting on the rigidbody in question?

Comment: @Serlite Thanks for your answer, i have done this, direction is lower the closer the same object comes to the touched area. 
The same goes for the magnitude of dir, which continuesly gets lower as the gameobject travels towards the point, and same for the velocity which starts at (3.8, 6.2) and goes to (0.4, 2.2) and lower as the object comes closer to the point :/

Comment: Hmm...It's possible that `GetPoint()` is returning a position which does not have the same position along the z-axis as the object's transform. The `normalized` vector will always be 1 unit long, but it starts as a `Vector3` - so when it gets cast to a `Vector2`, the z-value is lost. The closer your touch is to the object, the more this will impact the length of the new `Vector2`, since the z-value will be larger relative to the x- and y-values. Try storing the initial vector in a `Vector3`, set the z-component to 0, then multiply its `normalized` version with `speed` to use for `velocity`.

Comment: @Serlite Thanks for this, it was indeed what was causing the problem, and its now working as intended, thank you so much :)

Comment: Great! Can I write this up as a full answer so you can accept it, and we can mark the question as solved?

Comment: Ehm...well, I wrote an answer anyways, feel free to accept it when convenient so we can signal to others that you got your question answered.

Comment: @Serlite Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of the problem lies within this line:

```
Vector2 dir = (Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (touches [i].position).GetPoint (0) - obj.getGameObject ().transform.position).normalized * speed;
```

### The direction vector is denormalized due to a cast

When you calculate this difference between the touch position and the object position with `Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (touches [i].position).GetPoint (0) - obj.getGameObject ().transform.position`, you have to remember that this result may not be 2D - it is a `Vector3`. This means that it may have a non-zero z-value, if the result of `GetPoint (0)` and `transform.position` are not at the same position on the z-axis.

When you normalize the `Vector3`, its length becomes 1, but only if its z-value is taken into account. When you store this value in `Vector2 dir`, that `Vector3` is cast to a `Vector2` and its z-value is discarded. This means that the length of the previously-normalized vector is no longer guaranteed to be 1; it can vary anywhere in the range of [0,1].

### The cast vector's length depends on the relative size of the z-value

If you multiply this new `Vector2` with `speed` and use it to set the velocity of a rigidbody, the magnitude of the rigidbody's velocity will be between 0 and `speed`, rather than always `speed`. The reason why the object goes faster if your touch is farther, and slower if it is closer, is because the z-value (which will be constant) will become less relative to your x- and y-values the farther away your touch is. Here's an illustration to show how this will affect the cast `Vector2`:

[image]

Note how casting the normalized `Vector3` will result in a longer `Vector2` if the z-value is smaller relative to the other values. (The diagram assume x = 0, to make it easier to read.)

### The solution

Fixing this problem isn't too difficult - you just need to normalize the vector once the z-value has become 0, whether by cast or by explicit assignment. Then your direction is guaranteed to be a length of 1, and your speed will be constant. Here's an example:

```
Touch[] touches = Input.touches;
Vector3 dirRaw = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (touches [i].position).GetPoint (0) - obj.getGameObject ().transform.position;
dirRaw.z = 0;
Vector2 dir = dirRaw.normalized * speed;
obj.getGameObject ().GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = dir;
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.